# How to stop a thread when its in the wait()

Tags: java, multithreading, return, wait, notify

```
 while (!closingTime){ 

        depot.enterramp();
    }
```

This is to start the function as below

```
  synchronized (list) {

        while (list.size() == 0) {
            System.out.println(":: DEPOT\t:: " + "NO BUS FOUND IN THE APPROACHES DEPOT, WAITING THE BUS COMING");
            try {
                list.wait();

            } catch (InterruptedException iex) {
                iex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

**Currently my thread is waiting the notify()  [This code is in enterramp() ]**

```
public class Clock extends Thread {
public void run() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(15000);
        notifyTime();

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}

public synchronized void notifyTime() {
    System.out.println(":: CLOCK\t:: ALERT ALERT !!! DEPOT HAVE TO CLOSE IN 30 MINUTES, NO MORE ACCEPTING THE BUSES");
    closingTime = true;

    return;


}
```

**This is the clock sleep for 15 seconds and make the closing time to true**

```
 synchronized (list) {
            list.add(bus);
            list.notify();
        }
```

**This is my part of notify it**

The problem I facing is when the closing == true, but the thread is stucking in the wait() area, how do i can make the thread exit from the wait() when my closingtime == true ???

Comment: I believe that interrupting the thread is the correct way to go (`Thread.interrupt()`).

Comment: but the thread currently stuck in the wait(), I cant have any move until the thread been notified...

Comment: You need to notify the thread. Where do you call the last `synchronized`-block you have posted?

Comment: The first box of code is keep on go in the the second box of code, so when the closingtime is not true, the thread will keep wait() until invoked by the notify.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the `Object::wait` documentation, it says the following:

> Causes the current thread to wait until another thread invokes
>   the notify() method or the notifyAll()method for this object, or some
>   other thread interrupts the current thread, or a certain amount of
>   real time has elapsed.

So you need to interrupt the thread.

Comment: How to interrupt it when the thread is stucking in the wait(), because of no bus keep on generating, therefore there will not have buses go into the 4th box of code which consist the notify(). – Huat Lee just now   edit

Comment: Make sure another thread has an instance to the thread you're running, and it interrupts it when required

Answer (score 0):

a) Your exit condition (boolean closingTime ) AND the lock (on which synchronization occurs) should both be used by the waiting threads. Your code can wait while the list is empty AND the exit condition is false.

b) you are synchronizing on 2 monitors; the 'this' and the 'list'. If the critical zone was protected by just one dedicated monitor (it's somewhat ok to reuse the list), then adding to the list OR changing the closingTime exit condition could both use notify(). This means kicking the waiting thread out without interrupt, as it is intended for.

c) try to avoid notify(), use notifyAll() unless you really know why you should notify only one.

Answer (score 0):

In your logic you should wait if there are no buses AND it's not closing time. But you check only first condition. I propose to notify the thread when you set closingTime to true. Make these changes:

```
while (list.size() == 0 && !closingTime) {


closingTime = true;
list.notifyAll();
```

Meanwhile on interrupt() topic: it does get you out of wait(), but its logic is very different. It is indended for outside control, like a signal to halt execution and exit. So, when you want to stop waiting, use notyfyAll(), when you want to BREAK execution, use interrupt().